# using a java while loop to make a line of numbers negative

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while

I have a school assignment that goes like this: Read the int variable number. Assume that number ≥ 0. Output the numbers from number to 1 in one line (or an empty line if no positive number to print). In the next line, output the numbers -number to number on one line. Use space in both lines to separate the numbers.

I am not allowed to use any for loops and I am encouraged to use while loops. The output should be like this: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMt3g.png%5D(https://www.stackoverflow.com/))

I have been really struggling with this for hours. Please help. Here is the code I have so far. The main thing I am struggling with is the 2nd line and it not reaching back up to the higher numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner myScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int number=myScanner.nextInt();
        
        if(number<=0)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                System.out.print(number + " ");
                number--;
            }
            while(number>=1);
            System.out.println();
            
        }
        do
        {
            System.out.print(-number + " ");
            number++;
        }
        while(-number>=0);
        
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You fogot to ask a question. Please [edit] the post and add a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

In your first `do-while` loop (where you print values `0` to `number`, you are decrementing the value of `number` until it hits `0`

So, your second `do-while` loop assumes the `number` in question is `0`

Personally, I would recommend keeping `number` untouched and using a second variable for your loops.

Right after `int number = Scanner.nextInt();` just put a `int index = number;`

In your loops, use `index` instead of `number`. Right before the second loop, you should set `index = -number`

The `while` of that second loop should be `while(index <= number)` and instead of printing `-number` just print `index`

```
    Scanner myScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int number=myScanner.nextInt();
    int index = number;

    if(index <=0)
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print(index + " ");
            index--;
        }
        while(index >=1);
        System.out.println();
        
    }

    index = -number;

    do
    {
        System.out.print(index + " ");
        index++;
    }
    while(index <= number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is on the last line of your code.

```
while(-number>=0)
```

If `number` is positive, `-number` is negative, so it will only run your loop once.

Try this:

```
int aux = number;
do
   {
            System.out.print(-aux + " ");
            aux++;
        }
        while(aux<number);
```

Comment: Also as @mmartinez said, use this second variable I called `aux` to keep the `number` untouched